# Can I call a MSBuild Task from Mono XBuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, xbuild

Can I call a MSBuild Task from Mono XBuild?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126274.aspx

http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Same way as you would do it with msbuild, with UsingTask .

You can use AssemblyFile or AssemblyName attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t41tzex2(VS.90).aspx